# Clear specific row based on a column cell value

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a marco that allows me to clear everything on my sheet but I'm trying to make another action to only clear specific rows but not all of the rows where any of the column shows the word "Yes" will be clear off. I'm separating this action by assigning it to a button.

I have been on stackoverflow and some websites and found some codes that looks like it works but when i tried it on my sheet nothing happened. Not sure if it is my range being issue (Im still confused on ranges) or the code.

To give an idea:

- The ranges that contains data are A3:L100
- The Column that contains "Yes" is Column L3:L100
- Clear only specific rows without reformatting anything in the rows. 
  E.g Row 1 cannot be clear, Row 2 needs to be cleared, Row 3 cannot be clear
- When cleared shift row 3's data into row 2 replacing row 2's data.
- I'm working with up to 100 rows hence why the ranges of the data is at A3:L100

As of now when I run the script I don't see any row that contains "Yes" being clear off. I would really appreciate the help!

Below are my current codes from websites:

```
function Remove(){
      var depositid = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = depositid.getSheetByName("customer"); // sheet name is this "customer"
      var RANGE = sheet.getDataRange(); //do i have to fill in the ranges here?

      var DELETE_VAL = "Yes";  // Keyword to remove the row
      var COL_TO_SEARCH = 11; // Column L = 11

    function main() {

  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  var deleteSelectedRows = removeThenSetNewVals();
  var runTime = (new Date().getTime() - startTime)/1000;
  Logger.log("Runtime is: "+runTime + " seconds");
};

function removeThenSetNewVals(){

      var rangeVals = RANGE.getValue();
      var newRangeVals = [];

      for(var i = 0; i < rangeVals.length; i++){
        if(rangeVals[i][COL_TO_SEARCH] != DELETE_VAL){
          newRangeVals.push(rangeVals[i]);  
        };
      };

      RANGE.clearContent();

      var newRange = SHEET.getRange(1,1,newRangeVals.length, newRangeVals[0].length);
      newRange.setValues(newRangeVals); //not sure if this is the culprit
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear Row if column11 equals'Yes'

```
function Remove(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("customer");
  var vs=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
   if(r[10]=='Yes') {//if column 11=="yes"
     sh.getRange(i+1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).clear();//clear current row
   }
 });
}
```

Arrays start at zero. Rows start at one so i+1 is a row number when your range begins at 1 and sh.getDataRange() get all of the data on the sheet.

Comment: Could you explain how does the last part works? I would like to understand it.

Comment: Do those comments help?